# Rails: Named scope works on Class but not instance of Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms, named-scope

**Given the following code:**

**user_decorator.rb**

```
Refinery::User.class_eval do
  has_many :employees, :class_name => 'Refinery::Employee'

  scope :active_employees,
        lambda {
          joins(:employees).merge(::Refinery::Employee.active)
        }

end
```

**employee.rb**

```
module Refinery
  class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, :class_name => 'Refinery::User'

    scope :active, where(:retired => false)
  end
end
```

**running rails console...**

```
> ::Refinery::User.active_employees
 => [ .......... lots of records etc ]
> user = ::Refinery::User.where(:username => 'test').first
 => #<Refinery::User .... etc etc>
> user.active_employees
NoMethodError: undefined method `active_employees' for #<Refinery::User:0x000000051330f8>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `scope` is related to the model, and not to an instance of that model.

If you want to do that, you have to create a method that does the same.

At least, I think so...

Comment: This is correct. Scopes are class level methods, not instance level methods. @DJTripleThreat, ask yourself, what is `user.active_employees` meant to do? If the user is some sort of boss that can have employees under it, then you probably want to do something like `user.employees.active_employees`.

Comment: @MrDanA thanks for the insight. I'll try this. And Gustavo you are right those are class level methods. Thanks guys!